# How to check observer called from search page?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, catalogsearch

I am accessing observer (`controller_action_layout_render_before`) through this:

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_layout_render_before">
        <observer name="layout_render_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\LayoutRender" />
    </event>
</config>
```

My observer file

> **app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/LayoutRender.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

class LayoutRender implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory) {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        if (//PHP Check here) {
            $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
             $pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is, how can I check if this is accessing on search page?**

Comment: No answer... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check in your execute function:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('search.result');

    if ($block instanceof \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result) {
        $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
        $pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');
    }
}
```

This will check if you are on search page

Comment: Thanks Shoaib Munir for the short and to the point answer

Answer (score 2):

You can check the module, controller & action name in observer file in below way.

Pass the below class in observer constructor

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
```

Get module name, controller name and action name in below way.

```
$moduleName     = $this->request->getModuleName(); 
$controllerName = $this->request->getControllerName(); 
$actionName     = $this->request->getActionName();
```

Now you can perform your if condition

```
if ( $mmodulename =='catalogsearch' && $controllername = 'advanced' && $actionName == 'index') {
    // Your code part //
}
```

Below is the full code.

```
namespace Devi\Customcheck\Observer;

class LayoutRender implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ){

        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        $this->request = $request;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

        // Get the module, controller and action name  //
        $moduleName     = $this->request->getModuleName(); 
        $controllerName = $this->request->getControllerName(); 
        $actionName     = $this->request->getActionName();

        if ( $moduleName =='catalogsearch' && $controllerName = 'advanced' && $actionName == 'index') {
            $pageConfig = $resultPage->getConfig();
            $pageConfig->setPageLayout('1column');
        }

        // $this->_logger->debug('My Observer Check =>'.$routeName.' / '.$moduleName .' /'.$controllerName .' / '.$actionName); 
    }
}
```

Hope, you may get some idea now.

Comment: You are right, this can be done by this process. I can mark both answer, otherwise I will :) voted for your answer. Thanks

Comment: Nice detailed answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

There’s a simpler solution than what others are suggesting:

```
if ('catalogsearch_result_index' == $observer->getEvent()->getFullActionName()) {
    ...
}
```